# Make ltxdoc class use report as underlying class

Tags: document-classes, documentation, article, report

The `ltxdoc` class, designed for documenting LaTeX source files, is based on the `article` class. Beyond a certain threshold, the documentation may need to be divided in chapters and another class, e.g. the `report` one, would be more appropriate.

Hence my question: is there a way to document LaTeX source files using the `ltxdoc` class but with `report` as underlying class? Or is the best way to build the documentation in a separate document where the class can be chosen?

Comment: You could just save `ltxdoc` under a new name and change the `LoadClass` command accordingly, if you are interested in a simple hack.

Comment: Or using package `scrlfile` you could use `\ReplaceClass{article}{report}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `scrlfile` from KOMA-script.

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplaceClass{article}{report}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

That gives me the following

```
*File List*
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
  ltxdoc.cls    2007/11/11 v2.0u Standard LaTeX documentation class
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
     doc.sty    2010/02/04 v2.1e Standard LaTeX documentation package (FMi)
multicol.sty    2011/06/27 v1.7a multicolumn formatting (FMi)
 ***********
```

Unfortunately, as soon as a `\maketile` command is run, everything breaks. There is a pretty simple reason for that. `ltxdoc` loads the package [doc](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) as well, which is redefining `maketitle`. This way, you can use multiple titles in one document (according to the documentation of doc). Loading package `titlepage` lets the error dissappear. But there is one drawback: The command `\maketitle` isn't doing anything now.
*But*: You can save the original definition of maketitle (by the `report` class) and later (after `doc` is processed) you can restore it.

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplaceClass{article}{report}
\BeforePackage{doc}{\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\author{Some one}
\title{some thing}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\maketitle\oldmaketitle
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you want to do this is for you to decide.
By the way: `\BeforePackage` is also provided by `scrlfile`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `\ReplaceClass` from `scrlfile` and it could help me in another contexts but, unfortunately, it is clashing as soon as `\maketitle` command is used.

Comment: The hack proposed by me doesn't work as well. I'll have a look at it. Hopefully, i can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I updated my answer, i hope it is helpful.

Comment: Your edit was indeed helpful. I am nevertheless surprised that anything simpler doesn't exist since years `ltxdoc` class is used.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Maybe there is something simpler, and we just don't know it? ;-)