# How to customize `l3doc`?

Tags: doc, l3doc

As I'm currently writing a package and started to use `dtx` format I wondered if there are alternative classes just using `doc`, so I started to use `l3doc` (since I use expl3 syntax). I'm pretty satisfied with it, but the following points are some kind of annoying:

1. I'm using `variable` to describe variables and `macro` to describe macros (since `function` should be used in documentation not in code). How can I unify the styles of both (either with or without the bars in the margin, I'd rather like to have them)?
2. Is it possible to transfer this look to the layout achieved with `\DescribeEnv` (bars too)?
3. How should I markup Lua code, which is used by the package? Should I use `\NewMacroEnvironment` as the `l3doc` documentation states?

This question is not about:

- [Changing the documentclass of `ltxdoc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150386/124577) or
- switching to another class, which breaks `doc` functionality, but could eventually be used for documentation.

What I actually use and am unsatisfied with (sample `dtx` file, I have removed package call to avoid providing `.ins` file):

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<package>\RequirePackage{expl3}
%<package>\RequirePackage{xparse}
%<package>\ProvidesExplPackage{testpack}{2017/04/15}{0.1}{Test package}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
    \DocInput{testpack.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \begin{documentation}
% \GetFileInfo{testpack.sty}
%
% \title{The \texttt{testpack} package\thanks{This document corresponds to \texttt{termdoc}~\fileversion, dated~\filedate.}}
% \author{TeXnician}
% \date{\today}
% \maketitle
% \tableofcontents
%
% \section{User interface}
%   \DescribeMacro{\justdoit} My test \cs{justdoit}: here would be the function call
% \begin{function}{\justdoit}
%   \begin{syntax}
        |\justdoit|
%   \end{syntax}
%   \meta{description}
% \end{function}
% \end{documentation}
% \begin{implementation}
% \section{Implementation}
%<*package>
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\RequireLuaTeX
\RequirePackage{luacode}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{variable}{\mytl}
%   A variable
%    \begin{macrocode}
\tl_new:N \mytl
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{variable}
% \begin{environment}{luacode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\begin{luacode}
function justdoit()
    tex.print(1,[[Test]])
end
\end{luacode}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{environment}
% \begin{macro}{\justdoit}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\justdoit}{}{
    \directlua{justdoit()}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%</package>
% \end{implementation}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

*Update:* Here's an example output:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions to unify the styles of variables and macros, transfer the look to the layout achieved with `\DescribeEnv`, and find a way to markup `Lua` code in your `l3doc` documentation.

- Unifying the styles of variables and macros:

To unify the styles of both variables and macros, you can customize the `l3doc` environments. You can achieve this by modifying the `l3doc` package itself or creating a new package (or class) based on `l3doc`.

For example, you can define a new environment `my_macro` with the desired style:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{my_macro}{m}
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \variable \meta
    \begin{macro}{#1}
  }
  {
    \end{macro}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \variable \gobble
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then, you can use the `my_macro` environment instead of the `macro` environment in your code. This new environment will have the same style as the `variable` environment.

- Transferring the look to the layout achieved with `\DescribeEnv`:

To transfer the look of variables or macros to the layout achieved with `\DescribeEnv`, you can redefine the `\DescribeEnv` command to use the same style as variables or macros:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \original_describe_env: \DescribeEnv
\cs_new_protected:Npn \new_describe_env: #1
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \environment \meta
    \original_describe_env: { #1 }
    \cs_set_eq:NN \environment \gobble
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \DescribeEnv \new_describe_env:
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This code redefines the `\DescribeEnv` command to have the same style as the `variable` and `my_macro` environments.

- Marking up `Lua` code in the `l3doc` documentation:

To mark up `Lua` code in your `l3doc` documentation, you can use the `\NewMacroEnvironment` command as mentioned in the `l3doc` documentation.

Additionally, you can use the `luacode` or `luaexec` environments provided by the `luacode` package to properly format and highlight `Lua` code.

Here's an example of using `\NewMacroEnvironment` with the `luacode` environment:

```
\NewMacroEnvironment{luacode} % or luaexec, depending on your preference
```

Now you can use the `luacode` environment in your documentation, and it will be formatted and highlighted correctly.

These changes should help you customize the appearance of variables, macros, and environments, as well as mark up `Lua` code in your `l3doc` documentation.